# ggplot scale_fill_manual by finding like/wildcard values

Tags: r, ggplot2, wildcard

I am looping a function to calculate the races for all students in all courses on my campus, then aggregating the races and the grades they received in the course to create a grade distribution. I am also pasting the race sum to the race (e.g, African American (192)) to indicate the number of students in each racial group. I am then plotting that data for each course (600+ courses, hence the loop). My problem is that when I assign scale_fill_manual colors to each racial category it fails because the racial category changes from one iteration to the next: in the first it might be African American (192) and in the second in might be African American (87) so I can't select the scale_fill_manual value...that is, I cant code

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("African American"="violetred1","Asian"="orange3)
```

because the name for each racial group is constantly changing. so, my question is, is there a way to, much like SQL, apply a wildcard to the value...something like:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("African American*"="violetred1","Asian*"="orange3)
```

Or perhaps there is a better way to do this?

edit: i have columns for race, count, and racecount looking like:

```
African American, 192, African American (192)
```

so if there were a way to fill with racecount so the legend label for each group is Race (count) but then assign scale_fill_manual to the race column where the groups remain the same, that could work but I don't know how to make that happen.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(extdplyr)
library(pacman)
p_load_gh("trinker/wakefield")
set.seed(10)

df1<-dplyr::data_frame(
  ID = wakefield::id(n=100), 
  Race = race(n=100),
  Course = group(n=100),
  Grade =sample(1:5,100,replace=T))



df1

courselist=list("Treatment","Control")


myplot<-function(coursegrade){

  coursegrade<-as.character(coursegrade)
  subject<-df1%>%filter(Course==coursegrade)
  percents<- pct_routine(subject, Race, Grade)
  dat2 = subject %>%
    group_by(Race) %>%
    summarise(Count = n())
  percents<-inner_join(percents, dat2, by = "Race") 
  percents$Count <- with(percents, paste0("(", Count, ")"))
  percents$Race.Eth <- paste(percents$Race, percents$Count)
  percents$pct<-percents$pct*100

  temp_plot=ggplot(percents,aes(fill=Race.Eth, y=pct, x=Grade)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", colour="black", width = .8) +
    ggtitle("Grade Distributions by Race, 2015 - 2018", subtitle = coursegrade) + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = .5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,70)) 



  ggsave(temp_plot, file=paste0(coursegrade," - grade distribution.jpg"), width = 13, height = 7, units = "in")
  print(temp_plot)
}

lapply(courselist,myplot)
```

Comment: Maybe something like `colrs <- c("violetred1", "orange3");nms <- c("African American", "Asian");colrs <- setNames(colrs, nms)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to avoid this issue by adding the sum to the label in your ggplot code only where you really need it. For instance, suppose that you only use it in the title of your graph, then keep the label to "African American" throughout (so you can match it to its color) and use `labs(title = paste0(my_label, " (", my_count, ")"))`, where `my_label` would correspond to "African American" and `my_count` to the count.

Comment: but would there be a way to paste to the legend labels so it looked like

`***RACE***
African American (192) [blue color]
Asian (119) [orange color] ` --well this doesn't format well on here, but imagine a legend with title Race then each racial group and their associated count included in the legend

...I thought about this but I wasn't sure how to combine the columns within the labels for each racial group

Answer (score 0):

As @user2362777 mentioned, it is best to not perform this labeling within the ggplot code chunks. Consider creating a new column, or editing the original column, for "race" before feeding into gg.

Your options include:

- `base::match.arg` https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.arg.html?
- `grep` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/grep
- `str_replace` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_replace
- `gsub`https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html

There are other posts similar to this on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+partial+string+match+replace

Comment: i actually have the race and count in two separate columns and am combining them into a new column so that the labels within the legend include the race + count...otherwise I am not sure how to include the labels that way

Comment: A reproducible example will go a long way to getting you a better answer. At a minimum, providing the basic structure of the dataset would help. What I am suggesting is to add a new column (e.g., `race_label_new`), which will use one of the above mentioned partial match techniques to rename the old race label (`race_label_old`)  a new race label (`race_label_new`) which you will use in the ggplot chunks.

Comment: I recently did [something similar here](https://github.com/TrashBirdEcology/flgaCBC/blob/master/R/editNames.R), where I just used `gsub` to edit the "typos"/races.  Although this is tedious, it allowed me to become more familiar with the data flaws.

Comment: i have added a full reprex that will hopefully be helpful. The problem I am having is manually assigning the color values to each Race.Eth value because they change with every iteration because the count changes with each iteration...what i would like is to assign the colors based on the Race column (e.g., African American, Asian, etc.) and but have the categories from Race.Eth (African American (#), Asian (#), etc.) show in the legend. but if that isn't possible then I was thinking that partial matching within scale_fill_values on the Race.Eth category might work

Comment: I am unable to run your  function/reprex without error. Probably due to character/factor conflicts.

Comment: i think i found the issue, it also requires the packages tidyverse and extdplyr...they have been added to the reprex code